# Apache windows uninstall path

Tags: php, mysql, apache, registry, uninstallation

I'm trying to find the path of the uninstall file for apache 2.2. I can see it in add/remove programs, and tried to find the uninstall path in the registry under HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall but there is no folder for apache...

I'm trying to find the path because I'm making an install file which installs apache/php/mysql and want to uninstall any existing installations of those 3 beforehand.

I know that running the apache installer gives you the option of repair/remove if its already installed but I want the uninstall to be silent/automated, so that the end user doesnt have to manually select remove to actually uninstall the existing apache.

I hope this makes sense, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my WinXP x32 laptop there *is* a key for Apache (2.2.13), installed with the MSI, under

```
HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall
```

...and the uninstall string is

```
MsiExec.exe /I{UUID of key}
```

Just checked a Win2003 machine (Apache 2.2.19) at work and it is the same.

This probably doesn't help you very much, because you need to find the key before you know which UUID to pass to msiexec.

Looking through the other keys, this seems to be similar for all packages that were installed with MSIs.

Which version of Apache are you looking at? Because some older releases in the 2.2 branch didn't use MSI (if I remember rightly), I think they may have used InstallShield?

Comment: Yeh I eventually found that uninstallstring and had no idea what the stuff inside the braces was. Can you explain how that works? I could probably do a registry search for apache under the uninstall registry directory and then get the uninstallstring from there. I executed the uninstall string and the apache installer with repair/remove comes up but if I do it through add/remove it does the "remove" part automatically. I need to figure out how it does that.

Comment: Oh and I'm looking at 2.2.19 which uses an msi installer

Comment: @Michael In all honesty - No, I cannot explain how it works because I don't know. I have always been flakey on Windows specific things like the registry, because I tend to write in cross-platform languages (Java and PHP) so I have never really delved into it. I double up as IT admin at work, and I know how to fix certain things that involve messing around in the registry, but I don't know much about how it all works under the bonnet. Really, I think we're straying into the realms of [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/)...

Comment: @Michael the only think I can say (and this is only because I just tried it) is that you might find the answer by running `msiexec /?`

Comment: Thanks man, you've been very helpful. Have this green tick (I don't know if you get anything for green ticks lol)

Answer (score 1):

How did you originally install apache? Most of the time on Windows it is installed with XAMPP, WAMP, or some other similar bundled package. Try a search for php.ini or apache.conf, then look at the directory structure. That should point you in the right direction, you could also try

```
apache -k uninstall
```

Also take a look here http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/23569

Comment: Apache would be originally installed by their msi installer. I think apache -k uninstall just uninstalls the apache service, not the whole apache program. I think the uninstaller from add/remove programs actually uninstalls the service as well. Just trying to find out what file the add/remove programs calls to uninstall. Thanks anyway.

Comment: From what I understand, it does not uninstall the service. apache -k uninstall should be performed before add/remove. Not sure about the specific executable for the add/remove though :(

Answer (score 0):

Here are the instructions I followed when I uninstalled my Apache server on Windows 7: http://www.ehow.com/how_7361546_uninstall-apache-windows.html

And one more thing, when doing the command prompt instruction, be sure to run it as Administrator or it will tell you that access is denied.